# Prevent MATLAB from creating a new file when it can't find the file I want to open

Tags: matlab, ide

I will often attempt to open an existing MATLAB file from the MATLAB command window using something like:

```
edit exampleFile
```

Alternatively, I may press `cmd + shift + D` with the name of a function to be opened highlighted in the editor.

However, if the function I wish to open is not on the path when using either of these methods, MATLAB will irritatingly create a new blank file `exampleFile.m` in the current folder. This is extremely annoying. Is there a way to stop this? Ideally, MATLAB would prompt to see if I wanted to create a new file before actually doing it.

Comment: There used to be a prompt, but you most likely got annoyed by it once and asked it to not show up anymore :)

Comment: That sounds highly probable. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In File -> Preferences -> General -> Confirmation Dialogs, there is a checkbox that says "prompt when editing a file that does not exist". Check it.