# MATLAB does not prompt me when saving a file that is being debugged

Tags: matlab

When saving a file that is being debugged, MATLAB would typically ask me if I wanted to proceed and warn me that saving the file to disk would exit the debug mode.

Recently MATLAB stopped showing me this warning. At the moment, if I type `Ctrl-S` to save the current file, MATLAB exits debug mode automatically without asking.

Is there an option that reverts this behavior?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663659/prevent-matlab-from-creating-a-new-file-when-it-cant-find-the-file-i-want-to-ope/4663682#4663682

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me so the behaviour hasn't changed. I think that you selected the "Don't show this dialog again" option. Look under "General\Confirmation Dialogs" in the preferences.

Comment: You are right.I feel dumb that I didn't see that screen on the preferences menu.  The option says: ``Prompt to exit debug mode when saving file``.  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you update the question to remove the false assertion that the default behaviour has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it back on by: Preferences > General > Confirmation Dialogs > Prompt to exit debug mode when saving file